# jQuery: onchange function of a <select> id only fires after reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have an app in Rails 4.1. I am using the  jquery-rails 3.0.

I have the following javascript file `welcome.js` which loads `jQuery` and 
waits for an `onchange` event to be fired by the changing of a `<select>` in the DOM with a specific id:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var width_of_grams = $(window).width(); //TODO why is this being called here?
  var new_pic_height = (width_of_grams /7);
  $("img.gram_photo").css('height', (width_of_grams) / 7);
  $("#instafeed").css('height', 2*new_pic_height);

  $(window).resize(function() {
    var width_of_grams = $(window).width();
    var new_pic_height = (width_of_grams /7);
    $("img.gram_photo").css('height', (width_of_grams) / 7);
    $("#instafeed").css('height', 2*new_pic_height);
  });


  $("#school_application_fls_center").change(function(){
    console.log("Hey man why are you sleeping?");
    var center_id = document.getElementById("school_application_fls_center").value;
    var formdata = {center: center_id};
    $.ajax({
        url: "/application/get_programs_for_center",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: 'json',
        data: formdata,
        success: function(response){
          var options = $("#school_application_program");
          removeOptions(document.getElementById("school_application_program"));
          $.each(response.programs, function(i,item) {
            options.append($("<option />").val(response.programs[i].id).text(response.programs[i].name));
          });
        }
    });
  });
});
```

the `.change` function is only called after I reload the page with the `school_application_fls_center` id. otherwise even when I change the `<select>` it is not fired, I don't see my `console.log`, and Rails of course, does not receive the `POST` request that is supposed to be trigged by this event.

The same phenomenon happens on Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and Opera.

N.B. It is interesting to note the `.resize` events is successfully called when the viewport is change without fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should desactivate turbolinks gem... it is a mess with jquerying things

EDIT

You can use [jquery-turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) gem which makes your events to be binded with turbolinks

Comment: how did you know i had that gem installed?

Comment: yes! Thank you infinitely for your rails 4.1 intuition